# Regex - Replace Brackets Around Numbers With HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains text. I would like to replace any number inside the curly brackets with custom html. I am unsure if this is possible with Regex. I can identify the number and brackets with:

```
input.replace(new RegExp('\{\d+\}', generateHtml(num));
// not sure how to pass the number found in regex to generateHtml()
```

For example:

```
Input string : 'The other day I saw {3} cats'
Output string: 'The other day I saw <span class="num">3</span>'
```

Comment: Use the regex `\{\d+?\}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing group can be used.

```
const generalHtml = arg => '<b>' + arg + '</b>'
str = 'The other day I saw {3} cats and {4} dogs';
str.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, generalHtml("$1"));
// 'The other day I saw <b>3</b> cats and <b>4</b> dogs'
```

In this case, the `(\d+)` part of regex can be referenced by following `"$1"`.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I needed. `$1` was the part I was missing